# Record user input without Text Field?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my iOS Xamarin app, it has a passcode in. What I would like, is for the user to enter a number using the numeric keypad, then save the number that the user saved for use later, so that 4 numbers could be entered by the user and then saved for a passcode.

This would mean that instead of having a text box, I could have simply some circles that light up (or something along those lines) each time after the user enters one number. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Or alternatively, how would I make it so that I have separate text boxes which show the 'password circles' and then it automatically switches from one text box to the next after every number is entered?

Comment: You mean just a bunch of buttons like the number pad to unlock the phone?

Comment: @Eclipsed4utoo basically yes, this is also for when the user creates a custom passcode for this app.

Comment: I don't think there is anything built into iOS to do that for you. You just have to implement it yourself.